# Dropdown Script is lagging

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this dropdown script that creates a dropdown based on the value in column G. There are about 4 different values that can be in column G which should create 4 different sets of dropdowns. The data on Column G comes from a filter that is consistently updating with new submissions which causes this script to run pretty consistently as well. At times the script lags a bit and leaves the drop downs blank for a minute or so before refreshing. Do you guys have any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

```
function DropDowns() {
    var app = SpreadsheetApp;
    var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var draft = ss.getSheetByName("Time Off Action Items");
    var option = ss.getSheetByName("Options");
    var types = option.getRange(1, 1, 1, option.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var obj = types.reduce(function(o, e, i) {
        o[e.toUpperCase()] = option.getRange(2, i + 1, option.getLastRow());
        return o;
    }, {});
    var column = draft.getRange("H3:H" + draft.getLastRow());
    var Bcolumn = draft.getRange("G3:G" + draft.getLastRow());
    var rules = Bcolumn.getValues().map(function(e) {
        return e[0].toUpperCase() in obj ? [app.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(obj[e[0].toUpperCase()]).build()] : [null]
    });

    column.setDataValidations(rules);
    Logger.log(types)
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe share your spreadsheet to make a copy and test it? What do you mean by 4 sets of drop-down?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your statement

> There are about 4 different values that can be in column G which
>   should create 4 different sets of dropdowns.

I can think of one minor optimisation

Based on the value you can populate the dropdown with known values, then make call to fetch options, this will get us new options also. Then once we have the options we can update the validation options.

This way the lag will be lesser.